# Tracking Progress of HTTPWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, progress-bar

How can I track upload progress of `HTTPWebRequest`? When I scattered `Debug.WriteLines()` to track which parts of my code takes the longest time, i found out the function that took the longest time is

```
var res = req.GetResponse();
```

I could use `BeginGetResponse()` but I have no way of tracking progress still? I read from various articles that I should track progress when writing to request stream, but I suppose that happens locally and thus is nearly instantaneous

With `WebClient`, there is `webClient.UploadProgressChanged` that allows me to track progress, but I think I can't use `MultipartFormData` with that? And I can't have multiple uploads at once, not a really big deal tho, in my simple app

How can I then track upload/download progress with `HTTPWebRequest` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have events for tracking thins in the [`webclient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class